# Securing WIX subdomain connected (externally) to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-cloudfront

I'm relatively new to AWS and was trying to secure my WIX subdomain (api.example.co.za) which is connected to AWS. So far, I have an EC2 instance for the website, as well as my S3 bucket running. I have also set up my CloudFront and pointed my subdomain on wix (api.example.co.za) to CloudFront (df***.cloudfront.net) within WIX DNS records. I got an AWS certificate through DNS verification and attached it to my CloudFront. In AWS CloudFront, I also routed all requests to my S3 bucket. I also redirected all traffic from http to https in CloudFront

When I type into my brower api.example.co.za, I am able to access my website, but insecurely, just as before. But when I type https://api.example.co.za, the website is secure, but does not load the web content. When Inspect the web content in Chrome>Inspect>Console, I see the following errors

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://api.example.co.za' zone-evergreen.js:29** was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.example.co.za/users/5e7a2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: It seems like code in zone-evergreen.js tries to load resources over HTTP, instead of HTTPS, which is blocked as insecure. Whatever resource is being called there, make sure it's https, instead of http and is being called as such.

Comment: Have you looked at CORS ?